# Calculate sum based on previous or next row

Tags: oracle

I'm working with some data in oracle and the data is a slightly incomplete for the calculation I need to do. 
The table looks like this (customer is not unique):

```
customer | status_From | status_To | date_Of_Change
```

What I'm trying to do is get this data:

```
Customer (grouped by) | status | days in status (sum for customer as status)
```

Where status will be the date of one row subtracted from the date of the next row. The same status may appear repeatedly, sometimes sequentially, sometimes not. If there is not another row, I'd like to use the current date for the math.

So essentially, it's

```
select customer,
SUM(CASE WHEN status_From LIKE 'A%' THEN (?Date of next row?) - date_of_change ELSE 0 END) AS DaysAsA,
from Log
GROUP BY customer
```

Is there a way I can do this in oracle without having to do multiple queries (in coldfusion) and looping through them?

Comment: It would be helpful to include some sample data and the result you expect from that. It sounds like a gaps-and-islands problem, but I'm not sure quite how you want to handle the date that the status changes, and gaps in the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lead() analytic function to retrive value of the next row:

```
select
  ..
  ,lead(t.status, 1, 0) over(order by t.status) nextStatus
from
  table1 t
```

Comment: This is great, but I tried lead(date_Of_Change, 1, NOW() )  thinking now() would be a default and received an error for invalid identifier. How can I make it give me NOW if there isn't another row?

Comment: What is NOW()? May be you mean sysdate() ?

Comment: How can I make sure it doesnt grab the next row where the customer doesnt match ?

Comment: Nevermind, PARTITION BY Customer in the over clause seems to do it.